# How can I get the url of an image uploaded to Firebase storage and pass it to a constructor in firebase cloud store

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I want to pass the url of an image saved in Firebase Storage to my `Firebase` database but the local url of the selected image is what is being stored in the `Firestore` database instead.
This is the repository implementation;

```
    override suspend fun addImageToFirebaseStorage(userData: UserData,
    imageUri: Uri,
    ): Resource<Uri> {

    val username = userData.displayName
    return try {
        val downloadUrl = storage.reference.child(IMAGES)
            .child("$username.jpg")
            .putFile(imageUri).await()
            .storage.downloadUrl.await()

        Resource.Success(downloadUrl)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Resource.Error(e.message.toString())
    }
}




override suspend fun addImageToFireStore(userData: UserData,
    downloadUri: Uri,
): Resource<Boolean> {

    return try {

        db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).document(userData.displayName)
            .update(
                mapOf(
                    userData.profilePictureUri to downloadUri.toString(),
                    CREATED_AT to FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                )
            ).await()

        Resource.Success(true)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Resource.Error(e.message.toString())
    }
}
```

This is the **viewModel**:

```
fun addImageToFirebaseStorage(
    userData: UserData,
    imageUri: Uri,
) = viewModelScope.launch {
    userDataRepository.addImageToFirebaseStorage(userData, imageUri)
}


fun addIMageUrlToFireBase(
    userData: UserData,
    downloadUri: Uri,
) = viewModelScope.launch {
    userDataRepository.addImageToFireStore(userData, downloadUri)
}
```

This is the viewModel composable intialization:

```
composable(Screens.AboutMe.route) {
        val viewModel: SharedViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val state = viewModel.userDataState.collectAsState(initial = 
            null)

        val newUserData by viewModel.newUserData
        UserDataScreen(
            state = state.value?.copy() ?: AboutState(),
            newUserData = newUserData,
            onValueChange = viewModel::updateUiState,
            onSaveButtonClicked = { userData, uri ->
                if (uri != null) {
                    viewModel.addImageToFirebaseStorage(userData, uri)
                }
                viewModel.saveData(userData)
            },
            onImageSelected = { uri ->
                
     viewModel.updateUiState(newUserData.userData.copy(profilePictureUri = uri.toString()))
                viewModel.addIMageUrlToFireBase(newUserData.userData.copy(profilePictureUri = uri.toString()), uri!!)
            }
        )
    }
```

[This is the Firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKAqg.jpg)
[This is the Firebase Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oUon.jpg)

How can I get the url of an image uploaded to `Firebase` Storage and pass it to a constructor in `Firestore`

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: It is "Firebase Cloud Storage", or "Firebase Storage", or just "Storage".  And you are using the database "Firebase Cloud Firestore", or "Firestore database", or just "Firestore".  I edited your post to reflect these corrected names.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @. Besides that, since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Comment: @AlexMamo. It was your resource I was using as a guide and it's been very helpful but I got stuck at that point. Please go through the newly edited code and see if you can help me get the error

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. It's hard to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Besides that, are you able to read the data from the local storage, upload it to Firebase Storage, and read the URL? If yes, what is the URL?

Comment: @AlexMamo. Yes I was able to read the data and parse it and the read the url. This is the url that is being saved; content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A15543. And I've tried to correct the code please go through the corrected code. Thanks –

Comment: So this is the location `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A15543` from which you want to display the image, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes. But when I upload to firestore, I want it to be the firebase storage url and not the local storage url. When I run your resource app, this was the url that is saved in firebase database; https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/messageme-7a6d4.appspot.com/o/images%2Fimage.jpg?alt=media&token=7d3f95f3-42f7-4d41-989c-3a5d69ce834a . That is exactly what I'm trying to get

Comment: So to be 100% clear, now instead of uploading to Firestore the Firebase Storage URL, you're uploading the local path of the image, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo YES.  That is exactly is the problem I'm facing

Comment: Have you tried to use the exact code in repo? Does it work the same way?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes. I did. I'm still getting the same problem